# How do I connect a scanner and scan a document on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: printer, scanner, windows-server-2019, fax

I have a computer running Windows Server 2019 standard. I know that it isn't the typical use case for Windows Server, but I am trying to connect a Canon TR4520 printer/scanner so I can scan paper documents here in the lab. The printer is connected and can print, but I can't find any app/setting that will allow me to scan a document, and the printer can't find the computer when I try to scan from the printer's menu.

If I was on Windows 10, I'd just install [Windows Scan](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-scan/9wzdncrfj3pv?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), but I'm not aware of a way to install Windows Store apps on Windows Server.

It looks like I want to use [DSM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj134196(v=ws.11)), [but it was removed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/removed-features-19) in the 2019 server release.

Most of my Google searches landed me on [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2275828-document-scanning-on-windows-server-2019) question, which isn't quite relevant to me.

Comment: Have you installed the Desktop Experience feature? It includes Windows Image Acquisition (WIA).

Comment: I checked my services, and WIA is installed and running. I think my problem may just be that I need a command or gui to interact with the scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have installed the Desktop Experience feature that includes
Windows Image Acquisition (WIA), and have verified that WIA is installed and running,
you only need an interface to the scanner.

For scanner software, check first if you installed the Windows Fax and Scan.
(I'm not sure if it's available in Windows Server 2019.)

For more options, see the article
[12 Best Free Scanner Software For Windows 10 to Scan Documents](https://blogs.innovanathinklabs.com/best-free-scanner-software/)
(although several only have paid versions).

Comment: I still can't get Windows Fax and Scan, it doesn't seem like it is available unless I'm missing something. Out of that list, NAPS2 was actually free (and open source), and seems like a good alternative to WF&S. It can't connect over wifi, but that's not a big deal, I have a cable for that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Canon support document](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART171458), you need to make sure that "IJ Network Scanner Selector EX2" is running. To start it:

> From the Start menu, click (All apps >) Canon Utilities > IJ Network
> Scanner Selector EX2.

Once it is running, you can select your printer. While running, its icon will show in the System Tray area of the Taskbar.

To scan from the printer's front panel, follow the instructions on [this page](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART171862).

Comment: Good suggestion, but it looks like that software is meant for Windows 10. There is a Server 19 version, but it seems like it may be missing some features. I found a gui that works, it looks like the drivers are all there already.